# What are the technical specifications of modern reaction control systems?

Tags: propulsion, space-shuttle, reference-request, specifications

I am working on a realistic space flight simulator as a hobby, but I am finding it difficult to find technical information about modern reaction control systems (RCS) like those used on the space shuttle. Wikipedia only has much more general information, and any books I have found do not include specific data.

I am looking for information about reaction control thrusters in space planes, rockets or pods, but especially the Space Shuttles. I am concerned with the mass of the mechanical system, mass of the fuel, force output and electrical requirements. I am also interested in any general information, such as typical burn times, maximum burn times or thermal energy generated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The good old [Space Shuttle News Reference Manual](http://science.ksc.nasa.gov/shuttle/technology/sts-newsref/sts-rcs.html#sts-rcs) should get you started.  There is also good information in the [Crew Operations Manual](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/390651main_shuttle_crew_operations_manual.pdf) (section 2.22).

I know just linking is frowned on, but your question is so general that I'd just have to copy the entire sections and paste them in, which seems absurd.

Comment: A link is just what I wanted! I had no idea this manual was was there. Thank you