# Is RCS a good option to control roll during the atmospheric phase of the launch vehicle?

Tags: launch

Do rcs perform well in the presence of high aerodynamic forces?

Comment: Welcome, your question seems to be lacking information that would allow it to be answered. An arbitrarily large RCS could handle 'high' aerodynamic forces.  Suggest editing the question to either ask how a known craft with complex loads (EG space shuttle) achieved control or ask for details on existing RCS system mass and performance.

Comment: Before editing your question suggest checking the following https://space.stackexchange.com/a/8433/26356, https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43762/26356 and https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49772/26356

Comment: It's been used a lot, so somebody thought so https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20759/6944 https://space.stackexchange.com/a/56035/6944

Comment: @GremlinWranger shuttle didn't use RCS "during the atmospheric phase of the *launch* vehicle" except in some exotic multi-engine-out and/or propellant dump scenarios.

Comment: Easier to use aerodynamic surfaces and/or gimbal the main engine for thrust vectoring than use rcs for the ascent stage.

Comment: @Innovine unless you only have one main engine, then roll is problematic.

Comment: Roll isn't essential to ascent. Maybe if you have antenna only on one side of your spacecraft, or if you have aerodynamic control, but otherwise its not of much use. Pretty sure you could design around it.

Comment: @Innovine ok https://external-preview.redd.it/I7VrWhNC1Wt_1JqUIGCw1KF4Yf3DvWzLPnJjk9JTKJ8.gif?format=mp4&s=bf91c4b46bd5e97ea3a1c7d0506daf664fb1536e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RCS of any sort loses ISP in atmosphere, and thus thrust, the same as any rocket engine (because that's all they are).

However they will only become completely ineffective if the apparent pressure on them is greater than their chamber pressure, which never happens.

What is more of a concern is sizing the RCS to be strong enough to overpower the sum of the aerodynamic forces on the vehicle, which can be huge.

Realistically, aerodynamically active surfaces are much more practical in the atmosphere. Whether they be fins, or gridfins, or static surfaces(wings) or dynamic surfaces like the Starship's , erm,... flaperons (or whatever they've settled on calling those things)

Example: the X-15 plane used aero surfaces for control while in enough atmosphere to do so, and only when so high that the air was too thin, did it rely on its RCS for control.